# NSTimer to fire while device is locked

Tags: iphone, nstimer, clock, alarm, nsrunloop

I'm currently creating an alarm. I use NSTimer to schedule my alarms. My problem is when the device was put into locked mode my NSTimer doesn't fire. I think that the NSTimer will not fire because my app goes to suspended state when it is lock. Can you help me find a solution to my problem?

I've found some topics about UIBackgroundModes, but I don't know how it will help me.

Thanks..

The problem in UILocalNotification is when the device was in silent, the sound will not be hear.
My implementation was I'm using NSTimer to fire an alarm when the app is in foreground or device is locked but app currently running. When the applicationDidEnterBackground: is called I schedule the UILocalNotification as the alarm.

Comment: If you got solution then also let me know , i have to also implement that thing

Comment: Local Notifications is the right thing to use in these circumstances and it will surely work

Comment: @Aditya have you made local notifications sound when the app is silent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little trick to keep the device awake, even if the user locks the screen.

The downside is, that it costs quite a lot of battery life. I've written a blog post on how to do this a while ago. [How-To: Prevent iPhone from Deep Sleeping - blog.marcopeluso.com](http://blog.marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/)

This technique works on all iOS devices up to iOS 4.2.1 and I've got an approved alarm clock app on the App Store that uses this.

I have created a piece of drop-in code you can use. [MMPDeepSleepPreventer on GitHub](http://github.com/marcop/MMPDeepSleepPreventer)

Comment: Thanks... I've implemented it on my app and it got approved.

Comment: There IS some other way out there beside this hack as far as I can tell. These alarms are starting audio tracks while locked and in silent:

Alarm Clock Pro
My Clock
Wave Alarm
Alarmed
iHome
...

Comment: @MarcoPeluso I implemented your code to startUpdateLocation in my app but it is not firing the timer when the app is in the foreground locked.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a local notification (UILocalNotification) for this to work.

Check out [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Broch. I've edited my question. UILocalNotification was just my second option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Local Notifications for this purpose,even if your app is running in the background you can receive alerts via Local Notifications.

You can refer the below link for further details

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Aditya for your response but Local Notifications sound can't be heard when the device was silent

Comment: Obviously in "Silent" mode you cannot hear the sound of notifications,Local or Push,That kill the whole purpose of "Silent" mode if you can generate sounds in that mode.

Comment: Ok.That's the reason I'm not using the Local Notification to display an alert as an alarm, because how can the user know if the alarm did fire. I've seen some other alarm clock that can fire an alarm even the device have gone to sleep at almost 30 mins. And they can play a sound to notify the user that alarm occure. On my observation they are not using UILocalNotification because there's no any alert window that appear just like the UILocalNotification.